# Cannot Connect to the remote AWS server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

Im trying to connect to the AWS EC2 instance from my windows7 machine and i am getting the following error.
Connection to the server is closed by remote host.
Please help me to fix it.

```
λ ssh -i "MyLinuxKey.pem" ec2-user@ec2-13-127-91-20.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Last login: Tue May  7 15:31:41 2019 from 157.45.50.152

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
10 package(s) needed for security, out of 16 available
Run "sudo yum update" to apply all updates.
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-6-206 ~]$ Connection to ec2-13-127-91-20.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to ec2-13-127-91-20.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.

PUTTY-LOGS:::
2019-05-13 23:44:52 ----- Session restarted -----
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Looking up host "ec2-13-235-9-176.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com" for SSH connection
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Connecting to 13.235.9.176 port 22
2019-05-13 23:44:52 We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.71
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Using SSH protocol version 2
2019-05-13 23:44:52 No GSSAPI security context available
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Host key fingerprint is:
2019-05-13 23:44:52 ssh-ed25519 255 b0:77:f0:c0:15:b4:b2:99:38:45:4f:0c:bc:79:c1:df
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
2019-05-13 23:44:52 Reading key file "D:\softwares\AWS\keys\privateKey.ppk"
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Offered public key
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Offer of public key accepted
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Sent public key signature
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Access granted
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Opening main session channel
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Opened main channel
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Allocated pty
2019-05-13 23:44:53 Started a shell/command
2019-05-13 23:45:05 Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection
```

Comment: λ ssh -i "macX.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-66-251-133.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
Last login: Mon May 13 13:17:50 2019 from 157.45.61.171

       __|  __|_  )
       _|  (     /   Amazon Linux 2 AMI
      ___|\___|___|

https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-10-90 ~]$ Connection to ec2-52-66-251-133.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.
Connection to ec2-52-66-251-133.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com closed.

Answer (score 0):

I Accepted AWS offer to use the default security groups which included '**All Trafic**' ports.

And, after many and many times trying to connect on my new ec2 instance, I just realized that I should edit my used **security group** and manually add to **inbound and outbound the 22 port ( ssh ) !**

Connect to Linux box by specifying your PEM file, e.g.

ssh -i "file.pem" ubuntu@x.x.x.x

```
Make sure your PEM file has 400 permission (chmod 400 file.pem).
```

Comment: thank you for your response. i have checked the configs and it looks fine.

Comment: thank you for your response. i have checked the configs and it looks fine. using putty i'm able to connect to the server, but after like 20 seconds  im getting a popup saying puTTY error: *Remote side unexpectedly closed network connection*

Comment: Please go security group and manually add to inbound open the 22 port. And add the .pem file in putty in Auth. After that, it will be connected.

Comment: @RajeevGautam, from the logs he has provided I think he is able to SSH into the instance. So the security group should be open.

Comment: yes, im able to do ssh on the server. after logging in it is throwing following popup "Remote side unexpectedly closed by network connection" have installed putty with the default installation settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PUTTY ( for SSH ), please make sure to use "Seconds between keepalives" setting. You may find it on the left-side menu under "Connection" option.

For "Seconds between keepalives" you need to provide interval in seconds(0 to turn off). Putty will send network packets to keep the session alive.

Reference: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.71/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-connection